# tornado equivalent of delay

Tags: python, tornado

Is there an equivalent command in tornado for delay function without affecting the main process to sleep (thus the callbacks would execute even when the main thread is dealying a new function call)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
import time
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, asynchronous
from tornado import gen

class MyHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        self.write("sleeping .... ")
        self.flush()
        # Do nothing for 5 sec
        yield gen.Task(IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 5)
        self.write("I'm awake!")
        self.finish()
```

Taken from [here](http://css.dzone.com/articles/pausing-genator-based).

Answer (score 21):

Note that since 4.1 they've added a [`gen.sleep(delay)`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.sleep) method.

so

```
yield gen.Task(IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 5)
```

would just become

```
yield gen.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 7):

## May be redundant

## I like callback style

```
class MyHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.write("sleeping .... ")
        self.flush()
        IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(time.time() + 5, self._process)

    def _process(self)
        # Do nothing for 5 secs
        self.write("I'm awake!")
        self.finish()
```