# How to run a looping function asynchronously in a Tornado.WebSocket class?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I'm running a WebSocketHandler with Tornado, and I have a `while` loop inside the Handler. This loop blocks everything - which is very bad. How can I make the `tailstream()` function asynchronous (a.k.a. non-blocking)? (As it is now, `tailstream` blocks everything, and makes even new websocket connections impossible. I need it to run for each websocket connection.)

```
(...)
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    connections = []
    filters = {}


    def allow_draft76(self):
        # for iOS 5.0 Safari
        return True


    def open(self):
        self.write_message('open')
        self.count = db.my_collection.count() - 1
        self.cursor = coll.find(tailable=True, await_data=True, skip=self.count)
        self.tailstream()




    def on_message(self, message):
        print message



    def on_close(self):
        self.connections.remove(self)
        self.cb.stop()
        print 'connection closed'


    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def tailstream(self):
        while self.cursor.alive:
            try:
                doc = self.cursor.next()
                self.print2web(doc)

            except StopIteration:
                time.sleep(1)



    (...)
```

Comment: I guess I could just add a thread for `tailstream()` with `threading`, but it feels kind of dirty given Tornado has the `gen` engine and all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `while` not blocking it. But `time.sleep` do!

Replace it with `yield gen.Task(IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 5)` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128923/tornado-equivalent-of-delay).

If it will not help - we can think about whole structure of solution.

Comment: I'll try. Though the `while` loop runs forever - and just sometimes goes into sleep.

Comment: It runs forever for every connection? Looks like you have to rethink architecture. It must run forever, but only one instance with forever loop must exist. Create connections pool and iterate over it.

Comment: I'll have say 10.000 clients connected to the WebSocketHandler - each will spawn his own, I suppose. And I have about 100 msg/second from a tailable mongodb 'stream' that needs to be filtered differently for each WSH and printed to client. Would I be better off iterating, like you mentioned, with one 'streaming' connection to mongodb - or - each WSH having its own (async) connection to the mongodb?

Comment: I need to run a loop like that, but at the same time accept new WSH connections. (It's not the `time.sleep()` that blocks btw. :)

Comment: Are you sure that tailstream blocking clients? Try to run it with `print` statements only, without other operations. And look at behaviour.