# tornado asynchronous request does't work,what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

here is my code:

```
 class AsyncTestHandler(BaseHandler):
  def testTimeOut(self, callback):
      time.sleep(20)
      callback("ok")

  @tornado.web.asynchronous
  def post(self):
      user = self.get_current_user()
      self.testTimeOut(callback=self.respones)

  def respones(self,msg):
      self.finish(msg)
```

i have used "@tornado.web.asynchronous" with callback,but the request is not asynchronous,how can id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does long-polling work in Tornado?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428231/how-does-long-polling-work-in-tornado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado uses only one process and one thread. All the IO operations in it are asynchronous, which doesn't mean that they are processed concurrently. So, if you call `time.sleep(xx)` in your code anywhere, your Tornado process will totally 'stopped' for that time!

The correct way to sleep in Tornado is to call `ioloop.add_timeout`.

See [tornado equivalent of delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128923/tornado-equivalent-of-delay).

See http://caisong.com/Tornado%20don't%20use%20time.sleep%20.html.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, time.sleep isn't asynchronous, so the main loop is blocked, while sleeping. For running synchronous code asynchronously you can use a seperate worker thread.

```
class HugeQueryHandler(BaseHandler):

    executor = tornado.concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(5)

    @tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor
    def sleep_async(self):
        time.sleep(20)
        return

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        r = yield self.sleep_async()
        self.finish()
```